# AppDomain vs. System.Reflection when finding application name and version

Tags: c#, winforms, reflection

In trying to obtain .exe version number and name I see that we could use different ways such as:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FriendlyName //shows: myapp.exe
```

or use

```
System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name //shows myapp
```

Both classes produce the "almost: the same name, but my question is:

What is the difference between these two? Why use one over the other (forget performance)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assembly is more physical thing (if I can say that), while App Domain is totally in-memory only. App domain is where your app basically starts and interacts with the framework, and it has multiple loaded assemblies. If your main assembly happen to be a startup assembly in app domain, you might get same name for assembly and domain. In your particular case you started app with exe and your current domain is `app.exe`. But it is not assembly name, which is does not have a file extension. Assembly has its own version vs file version. They can match or not. If you  have application components, you can place this in any of them `Assembly.GetCurrentAssembly()`, and it will return you something else. But the main thing is, `AppDomain <> Assembly`. These are 2 different beasts.

*"Why use one over the other (forget performance)?"* Depends what you are trying to do. You use both things any time application is running. But if your goal is just to get your application information, such as name, file version, assembly version - use assembly

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to get information about the executable, you can also go a little bit differently and try this.

Note: This example retrieves information about the currently executing assembly. But this approach can gather information for any executable (not only yours).

Note: Json serialization is used here only to be able to show what information is available through the `FileVersionInfo` class.

```
string executablePath = new Uri(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase).LocalPath;
FileVersionInfo fileVersionInfo = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(executablePath);

Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(fileVersionInfo, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented));
```

The output is like the following for my very simple console application:

```
{
  "Comments": "",
  "CompanyName": "",
  "FileBuildPart": 0,
  "FileDescription": "ConsoleApplication1",
  "FileMajorPart": 2,
  "FileMinorPart": 1,
  "FileName": "C:\\Projects\\.....\\ConsoleApplication1.exe",
  "FilePrivatePart": 0,
  "FileVersion": "2.1.0.0",
  "InternalName": "ConsoleApplication1.exe",
  "IsDebug": false,
  "IsPatched": false,
  "IsPrivateBuild": false,
  "IsPreRelease": false,
  "IsSpecialBuild": false,
  "Language": "Language Neutral",
  "LegalCopyright": "Copyright ©  2019",
  "LegalTrademarks": "",
  "OriginalFilename": "ConsoleApplication1.exe",
  "PrivateBuild": "",
  "ProductBuildPart": 0,
  "ProductMajorPart": 2,
  "ProductMinorPart": 1,
  "ProductName": "ConsoleApplication1",
  "ProductPrivatePart": 0,
  "ProductVersion": "2.1.0.0",
  "SpecialBuild": ""
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This is new to me. After taking a quick glance of URI class, it looks like it is made for the web, not Windows Forms. However, it looks like it produces all the information I need. I can't at this moment prove that it always works for Windows Forms applications. I guess I will resort to less adventures. Thank you very much.

Comment: @NoChance This is actually not correct. *"URI class, it looks like it is made for the web, not Windows Forms"*. `Uri` lives in namespace `System`, not `System.Web`. It is used for all paths. Author of this answer has correct use of this. In fact, `LocalPath` would make a little sense in web environment in the context of URL. But for the files being used in the code base on the drive it makes perfect sense

Comment: @T.S. Thanks for noticing this. I stand corrected. Good point.